# Does anybody know how to fix "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Emulator.Controller, Version=3.0.0.0"?

Tags: visual-studio, azure

---

### Microsoft Visual Studio

### Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Emulator.Controller, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

### OK

Answer (score 5):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2644640f-f473-4d63-aa6a-4077714d0461/caquietexec-error-cannot-create-database?forum=windowsazuredata

sqllocaldb stop v11.0
sqllocaldb delete v11.0 
delete C:\Users\MyAccount\WAStorageEmulatorDb30*.* 
sqllocaldb create v11.0

Answer (score 3):

I have found that this is due to the **Windows Azure Storage Emulator** not being properly installed.  Normally this is installed as a dependency when you are installing the **Windows Azure SDK for .NET**.

Try reinstalling the SDK (which can be obtained from [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/)).  In my case, the install for the Storage Emulator failed because it was already running.  A reboot may be necessary before reinstalling.