# Cannot install windows azure emulator v3.0

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013

When i try to install  windows azure emulator v3.0 its shows some error.[image]

[image]

How can i resolve this ?

now i find this solution.....

```
There may be an issue with the sqllocaldb user database v11.0 during the install. You need to recreate it (see below).
```

As far as I'm concerned, my first install attemp left some files in my c:\users[user] directory :

WAStorageEmulatorDb30.mdf
WAStorageEmulatorDb30_log.ldf
The sqllocaldb logs would mention these files still existed and it would not erase them.

I just deleted them manually. Recreated the v11.0:

sqllocaldb stop v11.0
sqllocaldb delete v11.0
sqllocaldb create v11.0
And reinstalled...

Hope it helps

Comment: What did you try yourself already?

Comment: Before that i have to uninstall all 2.2 version azure tools.again update the tool to azure 2.3 version.but i cannot install this

Comment: Particularly Azure storage emulator v3.0 can't install and it shows some Could not load file or assembly exception

Comment: Did you tried the answer in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23131617/does-anybody-know-how-to-fix-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-windows)

Comment: @rene sir i dont know how to resolve this

Comment: The question rene is referring to suggests to re-install/repair the complete sdk: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/

Comment: @AndrewFlierman sir i am trying to install this but i cant.....

Comment: I had a similar problem and I had to go into the SQL Server Object Explorer in Visual Studio and remove the databases from within the (localdb)\v11.0 node. This can happen if you attempt to re-install the SDK for a second time. When you perform an uninstall if doesn't remove the databases files/SQL Explorer references.

Comment: @MotoSV sir right now its working for me... u can simply open cmd as adminstrator and paste this below lines one by one

sqllocaldb stop v11.0 
sqllocaldb delete v11.0
 sqllocaldb create v11.0