# Azure emulator ver 2.5 sdk gives error Could not load file or assembly

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm using VS2012 and installed Azure SDK 2.5
but after complete installation when I tried to run solution it gives me following error :

> Could not load file or assembly.microsoft.windowsazure.emulator version=3.3.0.0,Culture=newtural,PublicKeytoken=31bf3856ad364e35 or one of its dependencies.The system could not find the file specified.

Comment: This question appears to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23131617/does-anybody-know-how-to-fix-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-windows